# C# как вернуть список из класса?

Tags: c#

есть класс для получения настроек

```
public class DbConfig
    {
        public class DbConf
        {
            public string Server;
            public string Port;
        }

        public List<DbConf> GetDbConf()
        {
            try
            {                    
                    list.Add(new DbConf
                    {
                        Server = "34",
                        Port = "34"
                    });
                };
                return list;
            }
            catch (Exception msg)
            {
                logger.Debug(msg);
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

каким образом я могу получить данные кроме как

```
foreach (var c in DbConfig.GetDbConf())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", c.Server, c.Port);
        }
```

Comment: а каким хотелось бы? что на выходе хотите увидеть?

Comment: просто как переменные, доступные из любого места программы. что то вроде  c = DbConfig.GetDbConf();
            Console.WriteLine("{0} ", c.Port);

Comment: а, понял, вам нужен не список?

Comment: да, хочу видеть переменные

Comment: ну тогда ловите ответ

Comment: Если вам нужны типизированные настройки - рекомендую посмотреть на http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Configuration/YamlConfigProvider.html (там есть пример использования библиотеки из C#)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по коментариям список у вас излишен:

```
public class DbConfig
{
    public class DbConf
    {
        public string Server;
        public string Port;
    }

    public static DbConf GetDbConf()
    {
        var result = new DbConf();
        try
        {                    
            result.Server = "34",
            result.Port = "34"
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception msg)
        {
            logger.Debug(msg);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

вызов:

```
var conf = DbConfig.GetDbConf();
// используем как = conf.Server
```

Comment: а как переменные то получить?

Comment: @des1roer обновил

Comment: только  var c = DbConfig.GetDbConf(); 
            Console.WriteLine("{0} ", c.Server);

Comment: @des1roer ну это уже как вам удобнее, я только принцип показал

Comment: да не у вас до обновления опечатка просто была. а так да все верно

Comment: @des1roer, а да, была, вовремя заметил и исправил

Comment: Никогда, вы слышите, никогда не пишите и не предлагайте другим писать вот такое: `catch (Exception msg) { ... return null; }`

Comment: @PavelHritonenko, это переработка кода ТС, так что вопросы к нему